# Leaving luggage in Barcelona at midnight

Tags: luggage-storage, barcelona

I'm arriving in Barcelona past midnight, as my plane is arriving at 23:30. I was wondering where I can leave my luggage at this time; I checked on the websites of LockerBarcelona and others, but all of the lockers close around 10 pm or 11 pm.

If there are no left luggage facilities open at that hour, what other options do I have to leave my backpack?

Comment: Is it to pick up the next day before another flight ?

Comment: it is, but not before another flight, but before going to France

Comment: With what kind of transport do you arrive in Barcelona, which location do you arrive and how do you expect to spend the night?